# Android There is a way to merge/glue/stick couple of wav sounds together?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I need to know if the next example is fesible:

I have the sound files saved in say m4a and wav formats inside of my android app. Then I select say four files of which three are m4a and one wav. My output should be a file which is a mix of all the four files in m4a format. So when I play this single file it should sound like the four files are playing at the same time.

It will be appreciated if you cand provide some code.

Comment: Why not use any sound editor software to stitch the files together and then play it on android ? I didn't understand the proposal of your app maybe ,sorry...

Comment: Yes it's possible just put the final stitched file on a folder named "raw" in your app and then you could play it

Comment: So i want to put some wav, m4a files inside my app on raw folder from where i want to select a part of them and then stitch them into one file.

Comment: Well , my idea is to stitch all the files and make a single file then copy that file into your raw folder and then play it, are you trying to make a dj like app ?

Comment: something like that. so what sound editor software do you recomend, do you have some code examples ?

Answer (score 0):

here is a code that I'm using to play a video from raw folder

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.vidfull);

mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
```

Of course you will use audioPlayer class or equivalent .

Note that you don't have to input the extension of the file .

For the audio edition software I use Audacity

Comment: I don't think u understood what i want, i want to be able to glue some sounds inside the android app that i develop, not outside the app. Thank you anyway moujib.

Comment: Ok I was expecting that , well for small audio files check SoundPool here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html   A SoundPool is a collection of samples that can be loaded into memory from a resource inside the APK or from a file in the file system .I wish you luck and keep me informed ,it's an interesting app to develop